# CSS 2-line Menu & Sub Menu for Wordpress + Modifications

Tags: wordpress, css, menu

I NEED A **CSS MENU WITH MENU AND SUBMENU IN 2 HORIZONTAL LINES**:
Hovering on the menu, the sub menu will load on the second line.
I got a nice code for such menu: ***[HERE](http://pastebin.com/dUhMyxzM)***.

Now it's working as if-
- I hover on the MENU, if there is SUB MENU, they will appear
- I take off my mouse from the MENU, the SUB MENU will disappear

Though the color combination is not good, but the functionality is fine as I desired them to be as Horizontal in sub menu.

[image]

#### DESIRED MODIFICATION

Now I need the menu to be modified a bit, then if-
- I hover on the MENU, if there is SUB MENU, they will appear
- I take off my mouse from the MENU, the SUB MENU will disappear
- I click on the MENU, then the MENU will be selected and the specific page will load, and the SUB MENU will appear and be visible where they designated to
- I click on the SUB MENU, then the SUB MENU will be selected and the specific page will load and the SUB MENU will be visible too

It should be like: **[THIS MENU](http://socialchange.is)**

Where the modifications to be done?
I've tried:

```
.menu li:active > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 920px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  background: #315299; 
}
```

But it's not working. :(

**P.S.:** I'm using the menu in a WordPress site.

Comment: Ok, I got an update, and it's working with bugs:
.menu li.current-menu-item > ul,
.menu li.current-menu-parent > ul,
.menu > li > ul > li.current-menu-item > ul{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 960px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 23px 0 0 0;
  background: #315299; 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I made at last. And it's **WordPress-specific**:

```
.menu li.current-menu-item > ul,
.menu li.current-menu-parent > ul,
.menu > li > ul > li.current-menu-item > ul{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 960px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 23px 0 0 0;
  background: #E5E5E5; 
}

.menu li.current-menu-item > ul li a,
.menu li.current-menu-parent > ul li a,
.menu > li > ul > li.current-menu-item > ul li a{
  float: left;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
  background: #E5E5E5; 
}
```